# Automatically changing img src value with animation jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, background, slideshow, fullscreen

First of all, hello. I've been trying to achieve something in quite a long time. I'm trying to create a background fullscreen slideshow using jquery. I did achieve that using css animations but if you select a new tab and then go back to the tab with the css animation it starts lagging like hell. I assume that this wouldn't happen if using jquery. Also, i tried to create it as simple as possible WITHOUT using the already built jquery slideshow plugins but i couldn't.

---

And now i got an idea. For the background of my sites i usually use

```
<div id="background">
    <img src="background.jpg" class="stretch" alt="" />
</div>
```

with the following css:

```
#background {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    z-index: 0;
}

.stretch {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

So, is it possible to make the value of img src to change **automatically** and if possible to add some animation to it?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var urlArray = [
 'url1','url2','url3'
];
var slideShowTimings = 1000;
var i=0
setInterval(function(){
var $img = $($('.stretch')[0]);
$img.attr('.src',urlArray[++i%urlArray.length]);
},slideShowTimings);
```

try this.. this should change the background image after every 1 second(1000ms).
if you want to animate things then you should use $.animate() OR $.show() and $.hide().somethign like this;

```
var urlArray = [
 'url1','url2','url3'
];
var slideShowTimings = 2000;
var i=0
setInterval(function(){
var $img = $($('.stretch')[0]);
$img.hide(slow,function(){
 $img.attr('.src',urlArray[++i%urlArray.length]);
 $img.show(fast)
});
},slideShowTimings);
```

Comment: :) i just typed it here.. check the code and dont forget to mark as ans or upvote if this helped.